# How to compute the complexity of $T(n) = T(n-2)+T(n-3)+2T(n/3)$?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

$T(n) = T(n-2)+T(n-3)+2T(n/3)$ and $T(n)=1$ for $n<4$. 
I tried to compute the complexity of $T(n) = T(n-2)+T(n-3)+2T(n/3)$ using the recursion tree but it's not clear enough for me to make a guess and demonstrate it by induction? also, it should be computed given both upper and lower bound.

Comment: Note that you're not computing the complexity of anything. You're solving a recurrence relation to determine a function. That function could be used to measure anything at all, not necessarily the running time of an algorithm. This is a bit like saying you're trying to "compute the cost of 4.50+3.99": actually, you're just trying to add two numbers: 8.49 doesn't cost anything; it _is_ the cost, assuming the numbers represent prices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Comment: I can't find the complexity using the methods given in the links.

Comment: Use the techniques used for solving the Fibonacci recurrence.

Comment: High reputation-ers, before voting for duplicate, could you check how you will find and prove an asymptotic by Θ for this function? Once you are done, will you believe it is a duplicate to that reference question/answers? When I checked every answer there, I could not solve this question initially. I had to find something new. By the way, I believe that I am not bad at recurrence relations. If I cannot find the reference question good enough for this question, I doubt how many others can, unless only a loose big $O$ is sought.

Comment: I was referring to the step 3 in my answer/comment, where I had to find something new (of course, the grand scheme is, as well-known to experts here, how to enhance the induction hypothesis, which is, however, not covered (explicitly) in that reference question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Summary: $T(n) = \Theta(\alpha^n)$, where $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}\approx 1.324718$.*

### Find $\alpha$

Let $\alpha$ be the unique positive root of $x^3=x+1$.

We can solve the equation manually by the standard method, letting $x=w+\frac 1{3w}$ and solving $w$. If we trust [the online calculators](https://www.google.com/search?q=cubic+equation+solver+online) or you can use some software package such as MatLab, Maple, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-x-1%3D0) or Python [numpy.root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html), you can find all the exact roots or the approximate roots. In fact, since all we need is a positive root, we could also cheat a bit by just verifying directly the following quantity is a root. 
$$\alpha=\sqrt[3]{\frac{9+\sqrt{69}}{18}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{9-\sqrt{69}}{18}}\approx 1.324718$$

### Reference function $S$

Let $S(n)= S(n-2)+S(n-3)$ and $S(n)=1$ for $n<4$.

Claim: $\frac{\alpha^n}{3}<S(n)<\alpha^n$ for all $n\ge1$.

Proof by mathematical induction on $n$.

- The base case when $1\le n\le3$ is easy since $1<\alpha$ and $\alpha^3<3$.
- Since $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$, the induction step is easy. Assume the claim is true when $n\le k-1$ for some $k\ge3$. Then
  $$S(k)=S(k-2)+S(k-3)>\frac{\alpha^{k-2}}{3}+\frac{\alpha^{k-3}}3=\frac{\alpha^k}3$$
  $$S(k)=S(k-2)+S(k-3)<\alpha^{k-2}+\alpha^{k-3}=\alpha^k$$

### Last Trick

Claim One: $S(n)\le T(n)$ for all $n\ge1$.

Proof: It is easy to prove by mathematical induction that $T(n)>0$ for all $n\ge1$. $S(n)\le T(n)$ follows easily by mathematical induction.

Lemma: there exists a constant $c>0$ such that for all $n\ge c$, $\alpha^{\frac{2n}3} > 3n^2$.

Proof. This is obvious since any growing exponential function grows faster than any polynomial, a well-known fact that is (almost) proved in [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97507/91753). (We can take c=72, for example.)

Claim Two: There exist a constant $d>0$ such that $T(n)<d(1-\frac1n)S(n)$ for all $n\ge1$. (That factor $1-\frac1n$ is the "last trick".)

Proof. Let $c>4$ be a constant as in the lemma. Let $d=1+2\max_{1\le n<c}(T(n))>1$.
Let us prove $T(n)<d(1-\frac1n)S(n)$ by mathematical induction on $n$.

- The base case when $n<c$. $T(n) < d/2 \le d(1-\frac1n) \le d(1-\frac1n)S(n)$.
- Suppose the inequality is true for all $n\le k-1$, where $k\ge c$. Then

$$ \begin{aligned}
T(k)=& T(k-2) + T(k-3) + 2T(k/3)\\
    \lt& d(1-\frac1{k-2})S(k-2) + d(1-\frac1{k-3})S(k-3) + 2d(1-\frac1{\frac k3})\alpha^{\frac k3} \\
    \lt&d(1-\frac1{k-2})(S(k-2)+S(k-3)) + 2d\alpha^{\frac k3}\\ 
    =&d(1-\frac1{k-2})S(k) + 2d\alpha^{\frac k3}\\
    =&d(1-\frac1{k})S(k) - \frac{2d}{(k-2)k}S(k)+ 2d\alpha^{\frac k3} \\
    \lt&d(1-\frac1{k})S(k) - \frac{2d}{(k-2)k}\frac13\alpha^k+ 2d\alpha^{\frac k3} \\
    =&d(1-\frac1{k})S(k) - \frac{2d\alpha^{\frac k3}}{3(k-2)k}(\alpha^{\frac {2k}3} - 3(k-2)k)\\
\end{aligned}$$

Since $\alpha^{\frac {2k}3} - 3(k-2)k \gt \alpha^{\frac {2k}3} - 3k^2\gt0$, we obtain $T(k) \lt d(1-\frac1{k})S(k)$.

Claim Three: $T(n)=\Theta(\alpha^n)$

Proof: This follows immediately from the two above claims since $\frac{\alpha^n}{3}<S(n)<\alpha^n$ and $d(1-\frac1n)\le d$.

Comment: Thank you for our answer, I'm sorry but I couldn't find the formula.

Comment: The last step is the most difficult one. Adding back the term $2T(n/3)$, show that T(n) = $\Theta(\alpha^n)$

Comment: Thank you but is there another way to find the solution without solving the equation x3−x−1=0, since we didn't study the method to solve this type of equations yet?

Comment: If this is a homework exercise for beginners, then Rishabh's answer might be enough for you to get a full mark on this problem. My answer might be too advance to be expected.

Comment: Since $\alpha$ appears in the sharp estimate $\Theta(\alpha^n)$, there is no way to get round it unless we just want to show, for example, $T(n)=2^{\Theta(n)}$.

Comment: You do not have to solve that equation, though. If you have learned calculus, it can be shown that equation has a unique real root, which is between 1.2 and 1.5. We can name it $\alpha$ then.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, do you have a reference that explains more the method you used to find $alpha$ or a formula to solve this type of recurrence?

Comment: For linear recurrence such as the one for $S(n)$, you may want to study https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/. For this $T(n)$, which is sort of one of kind,  it is more like arts and experiences, although we can make some generalizations.

Comment: For linear recurrence such as the one for $S(n)$, you may also check [solving recurrence relation by generating functions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3135/91753) or search the web for [tutorials on generating functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+recurrence+relation+by+generating+functions+tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that $T(n) < 3T(n-2)$. This gives you the complexity as $O(3^{n/2})$. You can also observe that $T(n) > 2T(n-3)$. This gives you the complexity as $\Omega(2^{n/3})$. Now, you can at least tell that the complexity is an exponential one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way to find the complexity with the notation big theta?

Comment: Of course there is a way. As Raphael said "Use the techniques used for solving the Fibonacci recurrence". There are matrices involved and Eigenvalues. If you don't know what an Eigenvalue is, then solving this is tough.

Comment: Upvoted because the result is very easy to find and explain, and useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know how to find to use the Fibonacci method since it's much easier to find the equation to solve for the fibonacci recurrence?